# Brochure: how to make it?

Tags: html, flash, photoshop

I want to make a brochure similar to this one:
http://www.awf.ae/al_rowaad_advocates_brochure.html
I'm web developer but new in brochures, so what technologies are used in it? Where to get this flash animation, and how to insert the brochure in it? Thnx

Comment: I voted to close, only because this is pretty much the same as another question I already answered, and the answer still holds true.

Comment: Oh, and there is also: http://www.megazine3.de/home.html.  I updated my other answer to include it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Adobe CS (and know what you are doing) then Adobe InDesign does this!  Check out there new CS 5.5, it has some really nice interactive features.